# Single Word for Hair Clog

Tags: single-word-requests

i asking on behalf of someone.

What is a single word that could mean "hair clog" and is used ubiquitously.

Hair clog that accumulates in pipes (eventually you need plumber)

Thank you.

Comment: More general: a [**fatberg**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatberg).

Comment: Thank you for that term, fatberg. @WeatherVane the person I was asking for actually was searching for the term fatberg (he forgot about it, but this is first time I am hearing it)

Comment: "Hair clog" is certainly the most idiomatic choice in the US.  I've maybe read "fatberg" twice in my 70 years, and could only decode it by context.  Note that there is no law that says that every concept has a single word that can be used to describe/identify it.

Comment: @WeatherVane To my understanding fatbergs form in sewers, mainly large main sewers, whereas the OP's question seemed to relate more to domestic pipework. Also an important element in the formation of a fatberg is the presence of solidified fat and oil holding all the other stuff together. As far as I am aware there is no specific term for domestic blockages caused by the accumulation of hair.

Comment: @BoldBen that's all true. My comment said "more general" and OP then said that was the word the friend had been trying to remember, although the (edited) question now says "specific to hair" so it's unclear what was being asked.

Comment: @HotLicks "fatberg" is a neologism that was only recently coined.

Comment: Hot Licks - "Note that there is no law that says that every concept has a single word that can be used to describe/identify it."  New users should be compelled to read that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey This came up recently with a question I'd asked of similar ilk.  And,  as I said in my comments.  **No** is certainly an acceptable answer to any question of this type.

Comment: @WeatherVane The person who I was asking for says he was looking for "fatberg". Out of respect for this person, I will mark "fatberg" as an answer if you post it thus.

Comment: You need to change your question to cohere with the answer you chose. fatbergs are found in sewers not in pipes in your house. hair clogs are not found in sewers, they **are** found in pipes in people's house. So which is it?? By the way, I have a gizmo to stop hair clogs in my pipes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general term for a sewer blockage is a **fatberg** about which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatberg) says

> a congealed mass in a sewer system formed by the combination of non-biodegradable solid matter, such as wet wipes, and congealed grease or cooking fat.

**Fatberg** is a neologism from a combination of the words *fat* and *berg*, modelled on *iceberg*.

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fatberg) has

> **fatberg**
>   noun
>   UK
>
> a large mass of fat and waste material that forms in sewers (= waste pipes under the ground)

and also in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fatberg), and others.

Comment: I really dislike this type of question. The OP says hair clog and you say a clog made of fat. There is nothing that connects them except they are two types of clogs in pipes. Plus, yours is for sewers not for pipes.

Comment: @Lambie Do you dislike the question or the answer?   I don't think that dislike for Weather Vane's answer colors the question as bad.

Comment: I dislike the question because it has zero to do with answer chosen.  I didn't dv or upv the answer.

Comment: @Lambie I posted this answer because OP asked me to. I wish people would read the [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/514010/single-word-for-hair-clog/514175?noredirect=1#comment1246301_514010) properly and stop whining.

Comment: The OP needs to change the question.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/04/world/europe/sidmouth-fatberg.html?smtyp=cur&smid=fb-nytimes&fbclid=IwAR0ZnvUMCw4FpvhIzC2jaDMOZS0O2UiID1iE1RI1G1OsPsbe4Du_B1rhqV4

Answer (score 3):

Drano.com uses the term *hair clog*.

But, they also say:

[... here are 5 great ways to prevent **hairballs** from being your downfall.](https://www.drano.com/en-us/explore-clog-basics/5-smart-ways-to-prevent-hair-clogs-in-the-shower)

Drano, for those who aren't familiar with it, is a product designed to unclog drains by dissolving the oils, fats, and other accumulations that cause clogs.

I'd say that if you need a single word, use **hairballs**. It's recommended by the experts.

Interesting side note, if the clog were in the intestines rather than a pipe, it's called a **bezoar**.  When made of hair, specifically it's a [**trichobezoar**](https://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=8898).

Comment: Of course "hairball" is more closely associated with the things a cat coughs up.

Comment: @HotLicks No disagreement.  I'd personally go with hair clogs, but OP wanted different.  So, I went straight to the experts on all things that clog your drains . . .

Comment: 'Trichobezoar' sounds like something J K Rowling would come up with.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes. She mentioned bezoars in her books. But, this harkens back to the historical perspective when they were used as part of many traditional curatives especially for poisonings. In her books, they're used as a potions ingredient.

Comment: Hello David. Thank you for your thorough answer. The person for who I was asking for was happy with the term "fatberg"

Comment: Having just cleared a few drains, I would argue that hair and fat go together like love and marriage. You can't have one without the other. Of course, there are always exceptions. I personally wouldn't use fatberg on a bet, but it's certainly adequate.